# How to query a csv file contained in a varbinary column?

Tags: t-sql

I need to read a csv file contained in a varbinary(max) column and load it to a final table.

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP1-CU14) (KB4488535) - 13.0.4560.0 (X64)   Mar 12 2019 02:50:13   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit)

So far I have 2 tables involved in the process, the first is where the file is contained:

```
CREATE TABLE FileRepository
(
Id bigint IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
FileName varchar(20),
LoadedFile varbinary(Max)
)
```

The second one is where the data from the csv file needs to be inserted:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MyTestTable](
[Id] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[Name] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Description] [varchar](50) NULL,
[AddedColumn] [varchar](100) NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
[Id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY =     OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I have loaded my file using this query:

```
INSERT INTO FileRepository(FileName, LoadedFile) 
SELECT 'MyCsvFile' AS FileName, 
* FROM OPENROWSET(BULK N'D:\convertcsv.csv', SINGLE_BLOB) AS Document;
```

I have tried to Select it using:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX),LoadedFile)
FROM dbo.FileRepository fr`
```

The result was not what I expected, it only shows random characters.

What I need to do is something like this:

```
INSERT INTO MyTestTable
SELECT *
FROM (Select LoadedFile FROM FileRepository)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data is not Unicode, use `varchar` instead of `nvarchar`.

In other words, try this to see the text of the file:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(MAX),LoadedFile)
FROM dbo.FileRepository fr`
```

To parse the rows in the CSV (but not the columns), you can do something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #CSVData (RowData VARCHAR(1000))
BULK INSERT #CSVData FROM 'D:\convertcsv.csv'
SELECT * FROM #CSVData
```

To also parse the columns, you can use `STRING_SPLIT`:

```
SELECT * FROM #CSVData CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(RowData,',') s
```

And then a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT p.RowNum, [1] AS FirstColumn, [2] AS SecondColumn, [3] AS ThirdColumn
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RowNum, * 
    FROM #CSVData
) d
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS ColNum, * 
    FROM STRING_SPLIT(RowData,',')
) s
PIVOT (MAX(value) FOR ColNum IN ([1],[2],[3])) p
ORDER BY p.RowNum
```

Comment: Thank you Very much! the query you proposed do the job, however with large files it takes a lot of time, still i can use the result to prove that we should use a Bulk insert operation instead of loading the file to a column